# Applescript error 1700 when using list from selection instead of inbox

Tags: list, email, applescript

I'm a newbie in AppleScript, I got a simple problem:

```
tell application "Mail"
    -- this works:
    set mylist to subject of every message of inbox

    -- but why this does not work? (error 1700)
    set mylist to subject of every message of selection

end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 1700 means "Can’t make «script» into type item". Try walking through the selection as a list:

```
set mylist to {}
repeat with amessage in (selection as list)
    copy subject of amessage to end of mylist
end repeat
```

Comment: I would like to understand what is the difference between inbox and selection: aren't they both lists containing messages objects?

Comment: To be honest, trying too hard to understand why Applescript does some things is a recipe for frustration.  Yes, they do look the same, but in Applescript's mind they are processed somewhat differently.